# Time for submitting Supplemental Response & update 132 declaration

Tags: office-action, prosecution, mpep

we previously filed a response to Non-Final Office Action and 132 Declaration with 3-month extension. Then, Examiner called and verbally asked us to modify the 132 Declaration and cancel the withdrawn claims, then some claims would be allowable.

Can someone help advise on how much time we have to file this Supplemental Response and Updated 132 Declaration?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the call from the examiner was not a formal action, so there is not formal deadline. If you wait long enough you will get a final action that you do not want so,  if it will be more than a week or so to get the filing done, call the examiner and let them know when you plan to file.

Comment: I followed your advice and it works perfectly! Examiner now indicated informally when he would like it by. Thank you!